# Is there a way to convert Angular 6 app to Library?

Tags: angular6, angular-cli-v6, angular-library

I Have an Angular App on v6.
I built it as normal app, now I figured out that I need to import it into another app, is there a way for me to actually convert my APP into Library?

Tnx in advanced.